# How to build python debian package for all versions of python2.* (2.5, 2.6, 2.7)?

Tags: python, debian, python-module, dpkg

I know for python3, you can do something like:

```
%:
    dh $@ -- with python3 --buildsystem=python_distutils

override_dh_auto_build:
    dh_auto_build
    set -ex; for python in $(shell py3versions -r); do $$python setup.py build; done

......
```

But  how can I make python debian package for different version of python2.*? if I do:

```
%:
    dh $@ --with python2 --buildsystem=python_distutils
```

It only builds the default python2.7 version.
Help please, thanks.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Packaging

Answer (score 1):

You should Build-Depends on python-all.  All versions that are supported by the current system are then built.  For unstable, that is only 2.7.

If you want to build for 2.6, you need to run a system where that is a standard version (such as Wheezy) and built on that.  Like with other packages, if you want to build for an old release, you should build *on* that old release.  This is because while packages from unstable may work on stable, but quite often they will require dependencies from unstable.

So specifically, if your development machine is running unstable, set up a pbuilder chroot for stable and use that for building the package.  They will then be for the python version in stable (currently 2.6).